# Not an "unsafe operation" error: Incompatible types Object cannot be converted to Entry<String, Boolean>

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap

I have a Map in a class where I store a `String` key and a `boolean` value. Then, I return the map from the function `getMap()`.

```
public class FacilityMachines {
    private static Map<String, Boolean> map = new HashMap<String, Boolean>();

    public Map getMap(){
         return map;
    }
```

In the class below, I'm trying to fetch that map, and then save it to an external file, I also instantiate `FacilityMachines` there:

```
public class WriteFile {
    FacilityMachines fm = new FacilityMachines();
    private Map<String, Boolean> m = new HashMap<String, Boolean>();

}
```

In `WriteFile`, I'm trying to parse the map into a new HashMap:

```
public void saveFacilityInfo() {
    for (Map.Entry<String, Boolean> j: fm.getMap().entrySet()){
            String s = j.getKey();
            boolean b = j.getValue();
            oStream.println(i + ": " + s + " = " + b + ". ");
        }
}
```

`oStream` is just the variable for my `PrintWriter`.

The above yields `Object cannot be converted to Entry<String, Boolean>` error.

If I change the method signature of `saveFacilityInfo` to `saveFacilityInfo(FacilityMachines fm)`, and then use the `fm` variable to try to fetch the map at the line `for (Map.Entry<String, Boolean> j: fm.getMap().entrySet())` then I get a `cannot find symbol` on all the functions from the `Entry` interface: `entrySet()`, `getKey()`, and `getValue()`.

And before anyone asks, I've imported `HashMap` and `Map`, and also tried using only `import java.util.*;` to import everything just in case.

I've also tried extending `FacilityMachines` from `WriteFile` and got the same results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return the map on the FacilityMachines class getMap() method with the correct type

```
public class FacilityMachines {
    private static Map<String, Boolean> map = new HashMap<String, Boolean>();

    public Map<String, Boolean> getMap(){
        return map;
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting, had no idea that's how you return Maps with declared types. Thanks!